# How to find the six trig functions of a third-quadrant angle given that its terminal side lies on the line $x - \sqrt{5}y = 0$

Tags: trigonometry

I'm not entirely sure how to approach the solution for this question and could use some help.

The question is: "Find the six trigonometric functions of an angle in standard position having its terminal side in the ***third quadrant*** and located on the line: $x - \sqrt{5}y = 0$.

Do I find the $x$ and $y$ values from the equation and then solve from there? Or am I overcomplicating it and the point is $(1,-\sqrt5)$.

***Edit 1:*** Based on a hint received by @Piita, that the point I should use is $(-\sqrt5,-1)$ I came up with these solutions.

I am studying for a precalculus challenge exam, so I do not have access to any of the solutions in the practice problems.

$\sin (\alpha) = \frac{-1}{\sqrt6}\quad\cos (\alpha) = \frac{-\sqrt5}{\sqrt6}$
$\tan (\alpha) = \frac{-1}{-\sqrt5}\quad\csc (\alpha) = -\sqrt6$
$\sec (\alpha) = \frac{\sqrt6}{-\sqrt5}\quad\cot (\alpha) = \sqrt5$

***Edit: 2*** Thanks everyone for the help. This has made things a lot clearer for me! I’m attempting to take a precalculus challenge exam to avoid taking the course next semester.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please, learn to use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to type the math in your questions. Many users won't even read your questions if they are not properly formatted, let alone help you.

Comment: Note that $(1,-\sqrt 5)$ is not on the line. If you plug in $x=1$, you get $y=+1/\sqrt 5$. But that's in the first quadrant. You need to choose an $x$ value in the third quadrant.

Comment: @jjagmath noted. I approved some edits and updated the question.

Comment: @Andrei I updated the question with my answers.

Comment: @Piita I updated the question with my answers.

Comment: Third quadrant $x=-2, y=-1$; For signs in various quadrants: AllSilverTeaCups

Comment: @Piita are those the correct answers?

Comment: Yes they are, hence 'Well done'!

Comment: @Piita thank you!

Comment: @N.F.Taussig I thought that $\tan \alpha$ was $\frac{opp}{adj}$ and that $\cot \alpha$ is $\frac{adj}{opp}$

Comment: @charbs29 Note that in your text, you still give point $(1,-\sqrt5)$ which is not on the line and may throw readers off, but the answers are correct.

Comment: I realized that the point you wrote down did not match with your answers.  Given that $x - \sqrt{5}y = 0$, $x = \sqrt{5}y$, so you presumably based your answers on the point $(-\sqrt{5}, -1)$.  That said, by definition, $\tan\alpha = \frac{\sin\alpha}{\cos\alpha}$ and $\cot\alpha = \frac{\cos\alpha}{\sin\alpha}$.  These definitions are consistent with the definitions $\tan\theta = \frac{\text{length of opposite side}}{\text{length of adjacent side}}$ and $\cot\theta = \frac{\text{length of adjacent side}}{\text{length of opposite side}}$ for an acute angle $\theta$ in a right triangle.

Comment: To the downvoters, a precalc student did manage to solve this on their own based on a simple hint; your revoking looks deserved.

Comment: @Piita how exactly did you come up with the points $(-\sqrt5, -1)$? Is it simply $x = y$ and $y = x$? Where $(x, y)$ are either positive or negative depending on the quadrant that they are located in?

Comment: Variable $x$ has coefficient $1$, so you let $y=1$ and solve for $x=\sqrt5$, using $ab-ba=0$. Third quadrant then tells we need both of them negative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints:

1. Transform the equation $x - \sqrt{5}y = 0$ in terms of $y = mx + b$.
2. Graph the function you've just converted.  Use that graph to form a triangle.
3. Use the Pythagorean theorem to find the hypotenuse of the triangle.  (Does $m$ look familiar to you?)
4. In the third quadrant, which trigonometric function is positive?
5. Using (3) and (4), you can now find all of the trigonometric functions.

P.S. Your answers are correct.

Comment: Thanks @bjcolby15!